# how to monitor folder size using cloudwatch agent

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, statsd, collectd

Is there a way to monitor a specific folder size using cloudwatch agent?  The only option I see is for the whole disk.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/metrics-collected-by-CloudWatch-agent.html

Would any other options like statsd or Collectd have such option?

Comment: Is there a specific reason you need to use cloudwatch. There are functions in java script that can already show an output of a file / folder size

Comment: Yes i do need to send it to cloudwatch so that it can be seen as a dashboard and if required set alarms around it.

Comment: did you ever resolve this? @kumar, looking to solve this issue myself

Answer (score 0):

Yes, `collectd` can be used to get the size of a specific folder into the CloudWatch Agent.

First add the `collectd` section to your cloudwatch agent configuration file.

```
{
   "metrics":{
      "metrics_collected":{
         "collectd":{
            "collectd_security_level": "none"
         }
      }
   }
}
```

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/CloudWatch-Agent-custom-metrics-collectd.html

Make sure you use the `-a fetch-config` option to update the cloudwatch agent to use the new config.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/create-cloudwatch-agent-configuration-file.html

Then install `collectd` and add the `network` and `filecount` plugins to the config file.

https://collectd.org/download.shtml

Config file example: `/etc/collectd/collectd.conf`

```
LoadPlugin filecount
LoadPlugin network

<Plugin "network">
  <Server "127.0.0.1">
    SecurityLevel "None"
  </Server>
</Plugin>

<Plugin "filecount">
  <Directory "/home/">
    Instance "home-directory"
  </Directory>
</Plugin>
```

https://collectd.org/wiki/index.php/Plugin:FileCount